# Can I limit ad tracking using chrome by using multiple local browser accounts?

Tags: google-chrome, cookies

Would it make a difference, when using Chrome and multiple local user accounts, to limit ad tracking being that cookies do not pass to other local sessions?

Answer (score 0):

It would help, but your browser still has a "fingerprint" which can help identify who you are.

Check out this site to see some of the information you reveal to the internet:
http://centralops.net/asp/co/browsermirror.vbs.asp

Since it also reveals the IP address your coming from, pretty easy to figure out that you're the same person on different sites.

Something like uBlock or Ghostery can help provide some privacy.